# Surgery on links

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, surgery-theory

Suppose $K^m \subset Y^n$ is a link of spheres $S^m_1, \cdots, S^m_i$ with trivialized normal bundle in a smooth manifold $Y^n$. I can do surgery on $Y^n$ using $K^m$. Is it true that the resulting manifold $Y'$ is independent of the order in which I do surgery on $S^m_1, \cdots, S^m_i$? That is, if I do surgery on $S^m_1$ and then on $S^m_2$, is this the same as doing surgery first on $S^m_2$ and then on $S^m_1$?

Comment: Yes, it is. You may as well do surgery on all of them at once!

Comment: Yes, I realized order doesn't matter. There is a cobordism between $Y$ and the resulting manifold $Y'$ with $i$ critical points with different critical values. The order of the values is determined by the order we do surgery. But since there are no gradient trajectories between different critical points, we can move these critical points and change their critical values, hence changing the order we perform the surgeries.